# SQL 2005 Express on SBS2008 connection issues from Vista x32 SP2 machines

Tags: sql-server-2005, windows-vista, windows-server-2008

I have a VB6.0 application running at a client's site on Vista SP2. When attempting to connect to a SQL 2005 Express database on a named instance ([edit]running in Mixed Mode - not Windows Authentication Only), on a SBS2008 server, from THREE OF THE FOUR Vista workstations in the office I receive the following errors:

**"SQL Server does not exist or access denied"**

*(Using either the sqloledb provider or SQL-DMO)*

Of course, the fourth Vista Workstation connects without a problem.

I've tried;

1) Creating a UDL (data link) file in order to "triple" check my connect strings and even when attempting to connect here (selecting the Microsoft OLE DB Provider) I receive the same error when it attempt to refresh the list of available databases

2) I have checked firewall exceptions on the server and even tried the tests, with the firewall turned off.

3) I have added outbound exceptions for my application to the firewall on the Vista machines.

4) I have installed the SQL2005 Backwards compatibility objects.

5) I have installed SQL Server Management Studio on one of the offending Vista machines and this errors in the same way.

6) I have also simulated the test environment in our offices on virtual machines and of course, no problems...

I guess my question is, how to I find out what is different about the one Vista PC that does connect, as opposed to the three that do not?

(Update) Also:

A Virtual Server has been added to the SBS 2008 Server, running SBS 2003 and all those offending Vista Workstations connect without a hitch??

Comment: How is the server set to do auth?

Comment: Mixed Mode. I've tested with Windows Auth from the UDL but all other connections have been using SQL Auth for now.

Answer (score 0):

Can you telnet from the offending workstations to the TCP port that the SQL Server is listening on?  (Check the ERRORLOG file to get the dynamic port number.)

Is the SQL Browser service on the server running (required that it is).

Comment: I'll check the telnet suggestion thanks. The browser service is definitely runnings as one workstation can connect.